# Data inserted but when I read data it shows always null on firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have changed my firebase project and after changing it does not work at all. I do a lot of work by changing code in every aspect but got no luck and can not find whats the issue.

I searched a lot and read articles but I do not know why after changing project error occur.

Every time it shows invalid username, even my code is completely right. I use this code in my other project which works fine but here it can not. When I add data it successfully added but retrieval got error.

my code

```
user = username.getText().toString();
pwd = password.getText().toString();
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AdminUsers");

Query qry = reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user);

qry.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists())
        {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                String cpwd = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("password").getValue());
                password.setText(cpwd);
                if (cpwd.equals(pwd))
                {
                    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("login",MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
                    edit.putString("logged","true");
                    edit.putString("username",user);
                    edit.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(home);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    pd.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Password "+cpwd,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            pd.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Invalid Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        pd.cancel();
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

[image: Firebase data tree image]

Comment: This line looks very weird to me: `reference.orderByChild("password").equalTo(user)`. You're comparing something called `user` to the value of a property called `password`. Can you log the value of `user` and include the updated code and its output in your question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen user and pwd is just a string which get the value from edittext.

Comment: I get the user value from editText and then compare it with firebase value. When I enter admin in editText which i correct email, it gave me error invalid username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are at the node `AdminUsers`, to get both the `password` and `email`, you don't have to iterate so just remove the for loop:

```
for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
```

And use:

```
dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue();
```

Also make sure that the `user` value actually exist in your database. This query `reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user)` is like saying where email is equal to user_value

Comment: But it did not solve the issue got same error. Invalid username.

Comment: Yes I updated the code. user is the string which get the editText value from user.

Comment: Is user equal to admin? Instead of user write "admin"

Comment: I want to check data dynamically direct through firebase. If I write user equal to admin then it becomes static.

Comment: That's true but if the user doesn't write admin then it will always be invalid username

Comment: Good catch Peter. I completely overlooked that it was a single level. It means that the entire query is going to fail though, since queries work on the child nodes of the location on which you fire them,